# multiple deployment target values

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, mac-app-store

Is it possible to prevent my Mac app from running on specific version of OS X?

For example, I want to state that it only supports 10.9.5 and 10.10.5, but not on 10.10.4.

I know how to set the minimum supported version using MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET in Xcode.

Is it possible to explicitly black-list some versions of OS X (while still supporting earlier versions)?

The reason is that my app is crashing on due to Apple's bugs on specific version of OS X, and was rejected by the App Store team because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is nothing in iTunes Connect or Mac App Store that would prevent an App on a specific OS X to get downloaded.

You could program your app to show a dialog on launch that this specific OS X is not supported and then quit. And mention this in the Mac App Store description.

Comment: Does it comply with the App Store guidelines? Is there any app in the store that does this?

Comment: App Store Guidelines: Yes, I don't find any term that implies otherwise. Example App: Don't know, don't have an old system to try, sorry. We used to do it this way back with Lion 10.7.x and this was never an issue with approval.